# How to get issues from Redmine API REST

Tags: php, api, rest, redmine, redmine-api

Using the API [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org) using the wrapper [Kevin Saliou](https://github.com/kbsali/php-redmine-api), I am trying to get the [issues](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_Issues)  of a particular project but is not being returned correctly, both issues as the  `open` and `closed` are incorrect.

```
    $client = Yii::$app->redmine->connectRedmine();

    $issues = $client->api('issue')->all([
        'project_id' => 'id5-cli-portal',
        'status_id' => 'closed',
        'sort' => 'created_on:desc,status:desc'
    ]);
```

When the parameter is used as `status_id` =  `closed`, it returns a fixed number of elements 25.
The project above contains:

> Funcionalidade: 15 open / 86
>
> Suporte: 1 open / 5
>
> Manutenção: 7 open / 61
>
> Erro: 3 open / 20
>
> Pesquisa de Satisfação: 0 open / 0

And returns: `16 open issue` / `25 closed issue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have status definied that `count as closed`?

At the admin preferences you can set for every (?) status if it counts as closed or not. If yes the overview (the list you posted above) counts als issues as closed that have an status that counts as closed. Same for "open" (= all status that are not closed)

The API seems to only return these issues as closed who have the particular status `closed` and not all issues which have a status that counts as closed.

As I'm not native english I hope you get what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

use 'limit' => 100, in your array.

The API of redmine have a default limit of 25.